# Uncaught exception 'MongoConnectionException' with message 'Failed to connect to: localhost:27017

Tags: php, mongodb

I have successfully installed the MongoDB in localhost. I have tried to connect to the MongoDB using PHP.

It throws the error like this.

```
Uncaught exception 'MongoConnectionException' with message 'Failed to connect to: localhost:27017: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

Here is my code.

```
$username = 'user';
$password = 'pass';

$m = new MongoClient("mongodb://user:pass@localhost");
```

If I start command prompt as admin and run the `mongod` command, then it connects (No error using upper code). But I know it must be done by coding. So If anyone knows the solution, it will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you try to execute `mongo` command on your `<mongodb installation dir>/bin`?

Comment: try to connect to mongo without PHP for example with robomongo or any other client if this works then check if you are connecting to proper port and if your credentials are good

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have installed Mongo as a service, you need to start a `mongod` process first before you will be able to connect to  it using `mongo`. `mongod` is the actually database server, whereas `mongo` is the client. Check mongodb.org for instructions on how to run `mongod` as a service, instructions will differ depending on what platform you are using.